# parse any HTML to XML using html5lib

Tags: python, xml, html5lib

I need to tidy up HTML pages and convert them to XML in Python; losing some "bad" parts if needed.

I used **TagSoup** for some time, but it doesn't understand new "article", "footer" tags, and doesn't like "meta" when they are not in the head; making resulting XML almost impossible to process.

I like what **html5lib** does so far, but my fifth test (very weird tests) failed; when parsing

```
<div attr="val"">
```

using html5lib + **xml.dom** treebuilder, I got the following in the resulting XML string:

```
<div attr="val" "="">
```

which is not a good result for well-formed xml.

When I tried html5lib + **lxml** as a treebuilder, I got that converted to

```
<div attr="val" U00022="">
```

which is better, but the problem is that **lxml** "eats" closing tags/slashes for `<link>` tags, making them just `<link ... >` when outputting XML.

What would you recommend to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `method` to set an Element to be self-closing or not, something like this:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.Element('div', attrib={'attr':'val', 'U00022':''})
etree.tostring(tree)
'<div U00022="" attr="val"/>'

# parse as self-closing tag
etree.tostring(tree, method='xml')
'<div U00022="" attr="val"/>'
# parse as normal HTML
etree.tostring(tree, method='html')
'<div U00022="" attr="val"></div>'
```

Then just do whatever you want from it.
When you're trying to write from the Element, you can also add `method` too:

```
tree = html5lib.parse('<div attr="val" U00022="">', treebuilder='lxml', namespaceHTMLElements=False)
tree.write('yourfilename', method='html')
```

Printout:

```
<html><head></head><body><div u00022="" attr="val"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: somehow method='html' doesn't help, but method='xml' works, thanks.

Comment: @alex29, that's strange! anyhow i'm glad it helps :-)